# Best way to import single css files in a rails 6 views using webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, react-rails

So i already imported the application.scss with the tags

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and it works

however i want to separate my css files and call them in specific views like in the home/index view call

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home/index', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'home/index', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

ive achieved this creating a separate js file such as home.js and inside just importing my home.scss like this

```
import '../../stylesheets/home/index'
```

my question is, is this the correct way?

do i always have to create a js file to import my css file?

is there a better aproach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You don't need to create a separate JS file, just create a CSS "pack" for each view:

```
app/javascript
└── packs
    ├── application.js
    └── home.scss
```

In your view:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'home', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Demo app, branch with change: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/css-pack

Caveats:

1. **Using multiple "packs" per page (e.g. 'application' and 'home') is not typically recommended (a) in Webpacker 5**. Webpack has no way of knowing that you want to share code between packs unless you add special configuration to do so (see footnote). My answer above assumes you're not duplicating imports across bundles (or you're ok with duplication).
2. Webpack will still create a JavaScript bundle to load your CSS bundle so you'll still need both `javascript_pack_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag`

a. You can share code across bundles by using the `splitChunks` API ([Webpacker 5 docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5-x-stable/docs/v4-upgrade.md), enabled by default in Webpacker 6).

Comment: Just want to add to OP example: you can separate only the CSS or JS in packages. In my case, the JS file was unique for all and a different CSS file for admin views and users views.

Comment: @rossta, just a heads up that the link to `splitChunks` API docs is dead. Also, question: do you think the "refrain from multiple packs per page from happening recommendation" still holds even with webpacker v6 example of `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'calendar', 'map' %>` ?

Comment: @frostini Link fixed, thanks. Correct, my recommendation was true for Webpacker v5, but now splitChunks is turned on by default in recent Webpacker v6 release candidates. In theory, developers shouldn't have to think about the multiple packs problem as much. There are still some limitations/potential problems to be aware of, currently tracked as issues in the Webpacker repo.